# How to create the easiest countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html

What is the easiest countdown timer written in html/JavaScript with no days no calender but just and only pure and simple seconds, minutes and hours where a user can define how much time from a number to zero it will take to stop at zero. I have managed to create a countdown timer but I cant define from what number the countdown should start (UX type design, the user will enter the number)

```js
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

const TIME_LIMIT = 20;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

startTimer();

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}

.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
.h1 {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<body style="background-color:white;">
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Save the user's input in the TIME_LIMIT constant when you declare it.

Answer (score 1):

The number the countdown starts on is set on this line:

```
const TIME_LIMIT = 20;
```

So just set this to the user's input instead of 20.
Of course since it's a constant you cannot change it after first assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you could try use Timeout to set a timer to execute a funciton

```
var myVar =  setTimeout(myTimer, 3000);//starting the timer at the end of time it will end execute timer

function myTimer(time,limit) {//the action after the time has set
  
  
}
```

you could use Interval to display a counter

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {//shwing the timer
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

more info about interval https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
more info on timeout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp